# Convert big int to float in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I already search for this problem, but I didn't find nothing. The problem is that when I have a big int, like `16777217`, and I cast it to `float`, the real value is `16777216`. I cannot figure out how to avoid this problem. Note that I have to use `int` and `float`, because I pass the `int` to the `fmodf` function, which will automatically cast the int arguments to float.

Comment: Try `double` or `long double` and `fmod` in place of `fmodf`

Comment: This isn't a problem. A float simply has less precision than an int, and you naturally take a loss in precision. But by using a floating-point type you're saying that you don't care about more than a small amount of precision, so the result is as correct as it can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float` does have a limited number of bits so does not have have infinite precision.

`16777217` is the first integer value that a `float` (IEEE-754 `binary32` type) cannot represent precisely and it is stored as `16777216`.

Use `double` if you want more precision.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I thought about using double, but I was wondering if there exists a way to use floats. Well thank you

Comment: hi again, I tried with double but the same problem:

int i = 16777217

Comment: @Greennnnn this can only happen on systems with `double` the same type as `float` (or that don't follow IEEE-754). What is your system (compiler, OS if any, ...)?

Comment: hi again, I tried with double but the same problem:

double a = 16777217;
double i = 2;
double reminder = modf(a, &i);

This will give me 0 and not 1.... Im working on a mac, with text wrangler and console

Answer (score 3):

Most machines today follows ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559:2011, or the identical [IEEE-754 floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard.

The IEEE-754 single precision `float` can represent integer value precisely at most `2^24`, which is exactly `16777216`.

You can use `double` or `long double` instead. For instance, the IEEE-754 double precision `double` can represent integer value at most `2^53`. (approximately `10^16`)

Comment: To clarify, single-precision can represent **all** positive integers up to 2^24. Above this value, some integers can be represented and some cannot. The largest integer representable in single-precision is FLT_MAX ((2 - 1/2^23) * 2^127)

Answer (score -3):

Floating point numbers are imprecise. Integers are not.

Therefore to convert one to the other you will always have this problem.

So the solution is to decide on accuracy

Comment: *Some* float numbers are imprecise (the float representation of an integer > 16777216, and 0.1, for example). Others *are* precise: 1.0, 200.5, and 32767.3125. Just like some integers are "imprecise": MAX_INT + 1; that has the same problem, even though both MAX_INT and "1" *are* exact values.

Comment: @Jongware - It is a rule of thumb. Integers are precise provided they are within a given range.

Comment: Ed, but so are floats!

Comment: @Jongware - Integers are precise throughout the range. Floats are intermittent in that regard.

Comment: every float is an exact value "inside their range". But the range doesn't encompass 'all' numbers. Therefore, you *can* say the float representation of "1/10" is "not exact", but you cannot generalize and state "therefore 1/2 is also inexact". For me, it's no more different than storing π into an integer.

Comment: **Every** numerical arithmetic system is inexact. Their inexactness differs only in its nature, not its presence. Integers are not accurate throughout their range. For example, in integer arithmetic, `5/3` does not produce an accurate result. (I use “accuracy”, not “precision” as previous comments did. “Accuracy” is about correctness, “precision” is about fineness.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Heard of set theory?

Comment: @EdHeal: What I have heard of is not relevant to this issue.

Comment: This is not really a good answer whereas you seem to know what you are talink about. You could have at least given a proper example such as e.g. the very nice and complete description of the issue in the relevant wikipedia article on IEEE_754-1985: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985 Nobody is helped somewhat vague comments such as "Floating point numbers are imprecise. Integers are not." even if they are essentially correct.